# Existence of multiplicative inverse in field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) = \{a + b \sqrt{d}: a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \}.$ Show that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ is a field.

Everything seems obvious except for existence of inverses in the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}).$

Suppose $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}) \Longrightarrow \alpha = a + b \sqrt{d}.$ To prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ contains multiplicative inverses, observe that for a non-square $d$ and $a - b\sqrt{d} \ne 0$  one has
$$\frac{1}{\alpha} = \frac{1}{a+b\sqrt{d}} \cdot \frac{a - b \sqrt{d}}{a - b \sqrt{d}} = \frac{a}{a^2-b^2d}- \frac{b}{a^2-b^2d} \sqrt{d}.$$

If $a,b \in \mathbb{Q} \Longrightarrow a^2,b^2 \in \mathbb{Q} \Longrightarrow b^2 d \in \mathbb{Q}$ (since $d \in \mathbb{Z}$) $\Longrightarrow a^2-b^2d \in \mathbb{Q} \Longrightarrow \frac{a}{a^2-b^2d}, \frac{b}{a^2-b^2d} \in \mathbb{Q}.$ Hence $\frac{1}{\alpha} \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d}).$

Is this correct?

Comment: We need to make the remark that $a-b\sqrt{d}\ne 0$. So for the calculation to be justified, we need $d$ not a perfect square, and we need to prove that in that case$a-b\sqrt{d}$ can only be $0$ if $a=b=0$, that is, we must show (or remark) that this is true because $\sqrt{d}$ is irrational.

Comment: Is the fact that $ d\equiv 2,3 \pmod 4$ a hypothesis?

Comment: @AndréNicolas thanks for the suggestions, I will fix it.

Comment: You are welcome.  Things look fine apart from the little gap I mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is essentially correct.

However, your comment about $d\bmod 4$ is unnecessary (and sort of wrong, because you certainly can consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$ when $d\equiv 1\bmod 4$). Regardless of anything else, $d$ is an integer, so you know $b^2\in\mathbb{Q}$ implies $b^2d\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Don't you already know from $b \in \mathbb{Q}$ that $b\sqrt{d} \in \mathbb{Q} \implies b^2d \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @K.R.S. That is a correct, but irrelevant, deduction. Where in any of this do you have that $b\sqrt{d}\in\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Right, I got confused with $b \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. Carry on